Not able mvn clean install intellij Error injecting: io.micronaut.maven.testresources.TestResourcesLifecycleExtension
Not able to build the micronaut project, getting below error
=================
[WARNING] The POM for org.graalvm.buildtools:utils:jar:0.9.23 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Error injecting: io.micronaut.maven.testresources.TestResourcesLifecycleExtension
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector$XmlExtensions
  at XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:135)
  while locating XmlMapper annotated with interface TypeArguments$Implicit
  at LocatorWiring
  at TestResourcesLifecycleExtension.<init>(TestResourcesLifecycleExtension.java:67)
      \_ for 2nd parameter
  while locating TestResourcesLifecycleExtension

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_INJECTING_CONSTRUCTOR

1 error

======================
Full classname legend:
======================
LocatorWiring:                   "org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring"
TestResourcesLifecycleExtension: "io.micronaut.maven.testresources.TestResourcesLifecycleExtension"
TypeArguments$Implicit:          "org.eclipse.sisu.inject.TypeArguments$Implicit"
XmlMapper:                       "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper"
========================
End of classname legend:
========================

Tried changing maven version from the system did not help

As the error states org.graalvm.buildtools:utils seems to be missing its' POM, so Maven is not able to account for its' dependencies, which, in turn may lead to NoClassDefFoundError as Jackson Databind is not added to the classpath or incorrect version of the Artifact is added there instead.

Seems it is not Intellij IDEA related. So, removed the intellij-idea tag
